# Making a function parameter a variable within the same function

Tags: javascript

I want to pass my function's *size* parameter to be used inside the same function, specifically inside an 'if' statement.

```
function text_size(size){
    if  (size = '1'){
        alert('something')
    }
    else if (size = '2'){
        alert('something else')
    }
}
```

This function is called inside another function (didn't write the whole function):

```
 if (newImg.height > 750, newImg.width > 750){
    text_size('1')
}
else if (newImg.height < 500, newImg.width < 500){{}
    text_size('2')
}
```

As for now it always alerts 'something' regardless of the parameters.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

Change `if  (size = '1'){` to `if  (size == '1'){` (and do the same for the second if).

**Longer answer:**

`size = '1'` sets `size` to `'1'` and evaluates as `'1'`, which is evaluated as `true` in javascript. This makes the code inside the first `if` statement always run.

Comment: Might be helpful if you explain the difference in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function text_size(size){
    if  (size === '1'){
        alert('something')
    }
    else if (size === '2'){
        alert('something else')
    }
}
```

= assign a value to a variable

== do assertions between left and right conditions of the ==

=== do like == but also check type (string, integer, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (newImg.height > 750, newImg.width > 750){
  text_size('1')
}
```

should be (to use logically and, for or its ||):

```
if (newImg.height > 750 && newImg.width > 750){
  text_size('1')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Tzach said, the problem comes from

```
if  (size = '1'){
```

You have to use `size == '1'` instead.

Why? because if you use only one `'='`, in means that you are doing an assigantion :

```
var size = 0;
if (size = 1){...}
alert(size); //size is now equal to 1

var size = 0;
if (size == 1){...}
alert(size); //size is equal to 0
```